# How to change between multiple colors in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, animation, colors, android-color

Hey im trying to change a backgroud color between 5 colors in a endless cicle.

what i tried was this

```
private val myColors = arrayOf(red, yellow, purple, orange, green)
private val colorCycle = TransitionDrawable(myColors)


private fun myFunction() {
    this.background = colorCycle
    colorCycle.startTransition(2000)
}
```

Now I'm aware that this implementation only works between 2 colors "An extension of LayerDrawables that is intended to cross-fade between the first and second layer. To start the transition, call startTransition(int). To display just the first layer, call resetTransition()." but i can't find info in how to this that i want to do, an endless cycle between the 5 colors

if someone could point me to the right direction that would be perfect, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's anything that handles this in the typical libraries - like you say, `TransitionDrawable` only handles two layers, and it's more about fading between two things (usually images). You could technically make one for each transition (*colour1* to *colour2*, *colour2* to *colour3* and so on) and swap them around as you hit the end of each transition, but that's a bit of work.

It's probably easier to make your own utility class that can interpolate between a bunch of colours, something like this:

```
class ColourCycler(val transitionLength: Int, @ColorInt val colours: List<Int>) {

    private var startTime: Long? = null

    val currentColour
        get(): @ColorInt Int {
            // work out how much time has elapsed, and where that falls on the cycle
            val elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - (startTime ?: 0)
            val cyclePosition = ((elapsed / transitionLength) % colours.size).toInt()
            val transitionPercent = (elapsed % transitionLength).toFloat() / transitionLength

            // grab this colour on the cycle and the next (wrapping around the list)
            // and blend them using the ColorUtils package from the androidx.core library
            val colour1 = colours[cyclePosition]
            val colour2 = colours[(cyclePosition + 1) % colours.size]
            return ColorUtils.blendARGB(colour1, colour2, transitionPercent)
        }

    fun start() {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    }
}
```

That way, once you `start()` it, you can poll it whenever you like to get the blended colour for the current time. Here's an approach with coroutines, but you can use any repeating task approach you like - it just needs to get the colour, and update the background:

```
// in your fragment's onViewCreated or whatever

// initialise your cycle and start it
val cycler = ColourCycler(
    transitionLength = 2000, colours = listOf(
        Color.parseColor("red"),
        Color.parseColor("yellow"),
        Color.parseColor("lime"),
        Color.parseColor("cyan")
    )
).apply { start() }

// set up a repeating task to poll it and update the background
lifecycleScope.launch {
    repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
        // run continuously while the coroutine is active (not cancelled)
        while (isActive) {
            binding.layout.setBackgroundColor(cycler.currentColour)
            // update every 16 ms i.e. ~60fps
            delay(16)
        }
    }
}
```

A better approach would be to hold the `ColourCycler` object in a `ViewModel` so it survives rotations without getting reinitialised (and starting over at the first colour).

You also might want to drop the whole *started* state, and just turn the `currentColour` property into a pure function that takes an *elapsed* value and returns the appropriate colour, instead of deciding itself how much time has elapsed. That way you can keep track of the running time elsewhere, and do things like pausing the cycle by storing the current *elapsed* value, run it backwards, whatever!

Comment: If it's just a graphical effect without notion of a start time, you could use currentTimeMillis with a remainder operator so there would be no need for state at all to be able to keep it in sync through screen rotations.

Comment: @Tenfour04 yeah, that works too! Lots of options depending on exactly what you want